# Uploaded Image: how to get height and width? Restricting height and width?

Tags: templates

One of my channels allow users to upload images. Two problems:

1. I've defined a max width and height in the file upload preferences (and my channel field uploads to that). However, I am able to upload images beyond the max width and height.
2. When I am displaying this image to the browser, how do I get the image's width and height? The following doesn't work:

`<img src="{banner_image}" width="{width}" height="{height}" alt="{alternate_text}"></img>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using the ExpressionEngine File Fieldtype... In answer to #2, take a look at the [documentation for the file field](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/custom_fields.html#file-field).

Specifically, the [variable pair usage](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/custom_fields.html#variable-pair-usage) will allow you to pull in the `width` and `height`.

```
{banner_image}
    <img src="{url}" width="{width}" height="{height}">
{/banner_image}
```

---

I can't speak with much experience to question #1 since I've long disregarded the setting for max width and height in file upload preferences in favor of using plugins like [CE Image](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-image) (highly recommended!), but if you need specific sizes without using an add-on you can use the [Image Manipulations](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#image-manipulations) feature that is built into EE. Once you have those set up, an image at a particular size is available by name like this `{banner_image:custom_size_name}`.